# Как запускать функцию, пока другая активна

Tags: c++, qt

Начнём с начала
Я пишу (создаю) свою программу на C++ QT - Клавиатурный тренажёр
Если кратко, то у меня есть mainWindow - в котором есть 2 кнопки (старт и стоп)
С самого начала активен старт, а стоп нет (не кликабельный) - когда нажимаем старт - начинается игра.
Проблема в том что когда я нажимаю старт (запускаю функцию) - пока эта функция не выполнится до конца, кнопку стоп я нажать не могу, как и все другие кнопки, т.е запустить другую функцию.
При этом если вырезать "процесс игры" т.е функция старт выполняется очень быстро и я могу нажать на стоп.

P.S 
В самом начале функции (старт) я делаю кнопку стоп активной и старт нет, после чего следует логика игры.

Т.е мне нужно как-то сделать так что-бы во время выполнения одной функции можно было вызывать и другую (не из этой же функции)

Спасибо!

Comment: Если кратко, читайте про потоки

Comment: Зачем вы зипихали логику игры в код обработки нажатия старт?

Comment: То что текст большой, ~600 символов, и мне нужно проверять каждый символ введённый с клавиатуры + куда мне ещё пихать логику игры - если открывается окно MainWindow и там сначала нужно выбрать режим (урок), после уже нажать на старт